# PHP - Change fopen to curl

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I use this function with 'fopen', but I need to use 'curl' instead.

```
function rest_auth_xml($url,$method,$token,$chave,$xml)
{
$auth = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s',base64_encode("$token:$chave") );

$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>$method,
    'header'=>"Content-Type: text/xml\r\n" .
        $auth."\r\n",
    'content'=>$xml
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com
with additional headers shown above */
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
$conteudo = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
return $conteudo;
}
```

If anyone knows how to migrate, send your answer!

Comment: @vote-closer: I think it is clear what is being asked. @Paulocoghi, you would get a better response if you tried to do this yourself by reading through examples at the php curl http://www.php.net/curl manual and posting questions about any issues you have with what you tried.

Comment: As premiso sais. Just read through all the options of `curl_setopt()` and this is easily rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use to send post to any URL and get results:

```
public static function get_page_with_url_and_parameters($url, $params) {
        $query_params = self::build_post_variables($params);
        $curl_handler = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_params);

        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $output = curl_exec($curl_handler);
        curl_close($curl_handler);
        return $output;
    }
```

My build_post_variables looks like this:

```
private static function build_post_variables($params)
    {
        $post_string = '';
        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = urlencode($key);
            $value = urlencode($value);
            $post_string .= $key.'='.security::xss_clean($value).'&';
        }
        $post_string = rtrim($post_string, '&');
        return $post_string;
    }
```

The $params array you pass in should be in the form of $params['post_field']='value';

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PHP cURL page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as it has many examples that should help you out.